# Can I increase RAM from 8GB to 16GB on this model?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have this Macbook Pro with the following specs:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

anyone know if it's possible to switch out the RAM for an upgrade to 16GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't! As stated in [Apple MacBook Pro 13-Inch "Core i5" 2.3 Mid-2017 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-mid-2017-retina-display-no-touch-bar-specs.html):

> This notebook also packs 8 GB of onboard 2133 MHz LPDDR3 SDRAM (which could be upgraded to 16 GB at the time of purchase [for US$200], but cannot be upgraded later)

In a teardown of a similar notebook (a MacBook Pro 13" Touch Bar 2017) the RAM is visible outlined in green - it's apparently soldered:

Motherboard<sup>*</sup>:

[image: MacBook Pro 13" Touch Bar 2017 Motherboard]

---

<sup>*</sup> Source:  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/Qayrd2rbwLCQQoZv). Photo credit: Sam Goldheart and licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

Comment: damn, that is hardcore lame

Comment: It's increasingly common on HP, Dell and other laptops, too: in order to reduce costs, power consumption, points of failure and form factor.